# Firebase redirect to blank page

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, webflow

I'm building a website using webflow and am in process of adding authentication. I've managed to add all the basic code to enable email loggin. The problem arrises after a successful login by the user which results in a redirect to a blank page when i've specifically added my home page as the redirect-site(specified after the "signInSuccessUrl"). Does anyone know why this happens?

Before body, tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // FirebaseUI config.
  var uiConfig = {
    signInSuccessUrl: '<http://lundaspexarnas-superb-project.webflow.io/>',
    signInOptions: [
      // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    ],
    // Terms of service url.
    tosUrl: '<your-tos-url>'
  };

  // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
  var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
  // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
  ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
</script>
```

Before head, tag

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.7.0/firebaseui.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.7.0/firebaseui.css" />
```

Head code on all pages

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    Config details
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? Currently struggling with this

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [Firebase UI Demo](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/blob/master/demo/public/widget.html), the `signInSuccessUrl` parameter takes a relative URL. In your case, you'll have to set it like this :

```
signInSuccessUrl: '/'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your lundaspexarnas-superb-project.webflow.io domain listed in the *Authorization tab > Sign-in methods > Authorized Domains* in the Firebase console.